# Issue with option visibility in ui-select + parent div has overflow-x to scroll

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-select

I need to use `ui-select` within a parent `div` element which contains `overflow-x: scroll` style.

The problem is when we click on dropdown the option list hides behind the scrollbar. Please refer this image https://prnt.sc/oitdlw

I have created a sample at JSFiddle which shows the problem and expected result
http://jsfiddle.net/u4q82a71/4/

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't remove `overflow-x: scroll` for some reason :)
you can add this style to your `<ui-select-choices>`

```
.ui-select-choices {
    position: fixed;
    top: inherit;
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

then you can see it works fine even with your `overflow-x: scroll` hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. remove overflow-x:scroll

**css**

```
.inner {
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue,
the solution is to add append-to-body="true" to the ui-select element